# Custom HREF errors

Tags: views

I'm trying to implement a News archive.

Here is what the header(for ever page) looks like.

> [image]

Here is what the underlying HTML looks like.

> [image]

For this to work, I have to have my link as `http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive/` and not as 
`http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive`. Intended usage is `http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive/2015`, `http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive/2014`, and so on.

According to the view path, both can be accessible.

> [image]

If a user uses the second link, there will be an error as 2015 will get overwritten onto news_archive as `http://WEBSITE.com/2015`.

How can I the view load only on `http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive/`
and NOT as `http://WEBSITE.com/news_archive`?

Comment: Any reason not to just make the links relative to the root?

Comment: I think you just answered my question! haha

Comment: Well, I realized now, that hardcoding the links would then make view a little more difficult to export. as right now its in the staging site.

Comment: You're over-thinking this - if the HTML is in the header for that specific view page, and that specific view page has a definite path of `news_archive`, then portable versions of your links just become `/news_archive/2015` and so on. They would only need to be updated manually if the path to the view changed